# BeanCreationException Error creating bean … ClassFormatError … javax/validation/Validation need sustain

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have problem within my standalone application. It started before, but I updated eclipse or may be else one, and desktop application cannot start now.

I use there SPRING 3.2.3, HIBERNATE 4.1, SQLite.
I use 32x Eclipse at 64x windows, 
Eclipse used 32x Java JDK 
Project has Java Compiler v1.7
Project has JRE system Libraries 1.7.0_21 (there is included rt.jar)

I tried all combinations but nothing helped me still.

Please help me to understand what does it mean and how I CAN SOLVE THIS STUPID EXCEPTION?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ABNHibSessionFactory' defined in URL 
[file:/Q:/!PROJECTS/!JAVA/!DeskTop.PRJ/ABNPostBlank02/target/classes/META-
INF/database/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract 
in class file javax/validation/Validation
```

Here is stacktrace :

```
>> !
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ABNHibSessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/Q:/!PROJECTS/!JAVA/!DeskTop.PRJ/ABNPostBlank02/target/clas
ses/META-INF/database/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in clas
s file javax/validation/Validation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at info.abnsoft.java.postblank.gui.MainAppWindow.initMGroups(MainAppWindow.java:605)
    at info.abnsoft.java.postblank.gui.MainAppWindow.createContents(MainAppWindow.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at info.abnsoft.java.postblank.gui.MainAppWindow$4.run(MainAppWindow.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at info.abnsoft.java.postblank.gui.MainAppWindow.main(MainAppWindow.java:723)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:184)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 18 more
```

my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ABNPostBlank02</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABNPostBlank02</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.applerao</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernatesqlite</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3dep-brew</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>hibernatesqlite-maven</id>
            <url>https://hibernate-sqlite.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <spring.orm.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.orm.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

THE PROBLEM WAS IN JAVAEE-API IN REFERENCED PROJECT! IT WAS J6 BUT CURRENT PROJECT UPGRADE TO J7. TOPIC IS CLOSED. THANKS EVERYONE.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `javax.validation` dependency to the pom.xml, also make sure that you already don't have any jar linked to your application with the classes of this jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried - that did not help. I cleaned project, Update maven for project - nothing helps me.

Comment: it seems that eclipse is providing this jar, check on your runtime the jars linked to the app... I mean is there any more jar that have been used besides the ones declared in the pom.xml?

Comment: It is little strange for me but after I have cleaned project (and also delete all files from /bin & /target) and build Project - I found only project classes in /target folder. Whether should be there also all my linked LIBS & MAVEN jars too ???
May be that depends from SCOPE in pom.xml ?

Comment: I dont know how it is generated for a desktop app, but I think should have one lib folder inside the target folder. Anyway I suggest you to try to run this app in another computer, so you can check that if by updating the eclipse it also updated the jre version which might be causing this error. Also does it give you the same error if you run the project by the eclipse and by the maven generated file?

Comment: >> 
Few months ago project started in Eclipse with any problems. Everything was fine. I would like to get same situation. But that 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
spoils everything.
Many cases in internet described situations with Java5, but I have Java7 x64 in OS, in Eclipse too.

Comment: Also I tried to add hibernate-validaor; javaee-api; validation-api - these nothing help me.

Comment: THE PROBLEM WAS IN JAVAEE-API IN REFERENCED PROJECT! IT WAS J6 BUT CURRENT PROJECT UPGRADE TO J7. TOPIC IS CLOSED. THANKS EVERYONE.